# Writing a code to decrypt message from a text file

Tags: java, encryption

I got this question where I got to write a class named DecryptMessage that reads a secret message stored in a file called Mymessage.txt and decrypt the message. I really have no idea how to start. Please anybody help me? Much appreciated.

Below is what I've done and more or less I manage to got the answer thanks to whoever have helped and just to share the answers.

```
package decryptmessage;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class DecryptMessage {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int key = 10;
    FileWriter fWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Decrypted.txt");
        fWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        //if file not exist, create a new file. If exist, delete the file and create a new file
         if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.delete();
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        else
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Unable to create file");
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Mymessage.txt"));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            writer.write(decrypt(line,key));
            writer.newLine();
        }
        if(br.readLine() == null)
        {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to write into file");
    }
}

private static String decrypt(String s, int key)
{
    String decrypt = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
    {
        decrypt +=(char) (s.charAt(i) + key);
    }
    return decrypt;
}
```

}

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a ***summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem***, and ***a description of the difficulty you are having solving it***.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you tried doing anything?

Comment: Please, we can't do your homework. Try it yourself and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: ok. what i meant here.. was actually how on the world it is to subtract the 10 from each character. i dont understand the question.

Comment: Use [edit] option to add more details to your question about problem you are facing.

Comment: A text file cannot contian an encrypted message, unless you are using some pointlessly trivial encryption scheme, in which case you should stop.

Comment: its "contain" btw no offence. I would like to stop if I could but the question just says simple encryption of subtracting all by 10 if you read closely.

Comment: Hi guys I've got it and just to share the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first learn how to `read and write` onto files from [here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html).

Then, take your text and `encrypt` it with a `key`. When you're reading it `decrypt` it with the same key.

[Here's](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/) a small example on how to encryt and decrypt

**EDIT**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class EncryptDecrypt {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String plainText = "This is the plain text";
    int key = 10;
    String encryptedText = encrypt(plainText, key);
    String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, key);
    System.out.println("plain text: " + plainText);
    System.out.println("encrypted text: " + encryptedText );
    System.out.println("decrypted text: " + decryptedText);
    //==reading a plain text document
     // The name of the file to open.
    String readFileName = "c://temp//temp.txt";
    String writeFileName = "c://temp//encrypted.txt";
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(readFileName);
        FileWriter fileWriter = 
                new FileWriter(writeFileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        //buffered writer
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String encrypted = encrypt(line, key);
            bufferedWriter.write(encrypted+"\n");
        }    

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            readFileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + readFileName + "'");                   
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Now let us read the encrypted file and decrypt it
    // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "c://temp//encrypted.txt";
    System.out.println("The decrypted text is:");
    // This will reference one line at a time

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(decrypt(line,key));
        }    

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();            
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                   
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private static String decrypt(String s, int key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String decrypt = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        decrypt +=(char) (s.charAt(i) + key);
    return decrypt;
}

private static String encrypt(String s, int key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String encrypt = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        encrypt +=(char) (s.charAt(i) - key);
    return encrypt;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well there's not much to say, you should google every step you encounter. 
Do you know what a Class is ? If not, google it. Do you know how to read data from a file ? If not, google it. Lastly, you only need to manipulate characters, figure out what your "substracting 10" mean (alphabetical order ?), then it is quite easy in java.

Simpliest code sample :

```
        char c = 'c';
        System.out.println(c);
        c = (char) (c + 5);
        System.out.println(c); //is now h
```

There are multiple tutorials covering these, if you're still struggling your teacher should also be able to help you as long as you prove you have done some searches.

Answer (score -1):

Just analyse the text with a bufferedReader

```
 try{
     // open input stream test.txt for reading purpose.
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("c:/test.txt");
     while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(thisLine);
     }       
  }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}
}

And while you're reading the text, just analyse every char and make it -10

```
 System.out.print(currentchar-10)
```

Seems like the easiest way to do it to me

Comment: What do you think is type of result `char`-`int`?

Comment: Well i used this method long time ago,and if my memory is good it translates the char into the ASCII value and return another char with the new ASCII value.  So the returned value must be a char. Maybe try currentchar-'10'
Maybe there are some test to do if you want to have only alphabet letters and no special symbols

Comment: I am trying to point that `System.out.println('z'-10);` will print `112` because `-` operator will change `char` operand to `int` which will result in `122-10`. If we later want to print character which is represented by `112` we need to either store it in char variable first, or cast result to `char` like `System.out.println((char)('z'-10));` which now will print `p`.

Comment: exactly...and thats where i'm stuck...its like what does it means by the subtracting by 10. if its a "Z" and subtract by 10 means it becomes a "Q". then what about a "A".

Comment: Make a little test. If the ASCII value of your current char is J or less, add 16 to it instead of substract 10, so u'll have Z for J, Y for I etc...

Comment: so I have to change them to ASCII subtract by 10 and change back to a letter. is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, you just have to check the ASCII value. If the value of the letter is 106 or less, Add 16 instead of substracting 10. So you have J -> Z , I -> Y, H-> X etc....